# Ordnance survey boundary line .shp files?

Tags: shapefile

I would like to make a shapefile of Great Britain's counties.

I have downloaded the [boundary-line data](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/Boundary-Line-stylesheets/archive/master.zip) from ordnance survey:

The unzipped file appears to contain two file types: .lyr and .qml.

How do I convert one of these into the shp format, or where can I get hold of the shp equivalents?

Comment: Please see this q&a on converting .lyr to .shp  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129632/how-to-convert-lyr-to-shp-in-arcmap-10-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundary-line.html for the actual data. Hang on to those files if you want the style the shapefiles.