# Merging 3 x, y csv into 1 and save to file geodatabase using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

```
import arcpy
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/GEO/EX1/EX1/"
arcpy.Merge_management(["Crimes_-_2010", "Crimes_-_2011","Crimes_-_2012"], 
                       "C:/GEO/EX1/EX1/NEWDB.gdb")
```

How do I geocode 3 csv files create a new feature class crime_new?

I am just starting out with this, and I could not find anything in the docs/Google. The CSV has `X Coordinate` and `Y Coordinate` Columns.

Comment: Have you successfully geocoded one CSV file yet?  If not, then I think researching/asking about how to do that should precede this question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I read this,  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/geocoding/geocode-file.htm. However, I don't understand the field mapping part, Do Ihave to write the details of all the columns in the csv..I just need to be pointed in a direction where I can read up on this..The python part of arcpy seems to have less information on the net.

Comment: Are you saying you already have coordinates in the file? This isn't explicitly clear in your wording. If so you don't need to geocode, you just need to Make XY Event Layer https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/make-xy-event-layer.htm

Comment: @JClarkson I made the layer file for one of the csv. However, That isn't a feautre class..the ouput is a layer file..How do I go about getting the feature class? Or is it already a feature class as this suggests? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129632/converting-lyr-to-shp-in-arcmap#:~:text=shp)%20is%20a%20vector%20data,other%20layer%20properties%2C%20including%20symbology.

Comment: The first bullet point under the Usage heading on the link I sent describes the tools to use for making the layer permanent (i.e. a feature class)

Comment: @JClarkson Thank you very much.